# Vue: Editing a gmap custom marker

Tags: google-maps, vue.js, google-maps-markers

We need to build a set of custom markers in Vue for a google map that can be reused as things change on the map. There will be more than a 100 markers on the map and the map will be visible for more than 3 hours on screen at a time. Deleting and adding marks is not an option as Google maps bleed memory and crashes the browser over time.

Comment: The JavaScript API can definitely handle a map that shows 100 (custom) markers if e.g. you use clustering: please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed this by breaking and re-building Vue.(sort of)

What we did was to build a **Container component** inside the **GMap component**. This **Container component** house a list of **Value components**. Each of the **Value components** is targeted with the use of #ref.

```
// Container component
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="index in markerNumber" :key="index">
      <ValuesComponent :ref="'mk_' + index" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


// script
editMarker(counter, lat, lng, icon){
  const name = 'mk_' + counter
    if (typeof this.$refs[name] !== 'undefined') {
      this.$refs[name][0].lat = lat // targets the lat of the Value component
      this.$refs[name][0].lng = lng
      this.$refs[name][0].icon = icon
    }
}



// Values component
<template>
  <GmapCustomMarker
    :marker="{ 'lat': lat, 'lng': lng }"
  >
    <svg-icon :icon="icon" />
  </GmapCustomMarker>
</template>

// script
  data: function() {
    return {
      lat: 0,
      lng: 0,
      icon: ''
    }
  }
```

These **Value components** house the **Custom Marker component** and a set of values that determines how the **Custom Marker** looks and it's position. By changing these values, you change the marker through its reactive variables. The values in this **Value components** is set to 0 and blank so, although they are not visible they are there. For large Value sets this makes the map quite slow.

Managing of the **Value components** are done by the **Container component**. It first zero all **Value components**, then populate them from the top until it runs out of markers(this should not happen if you manage your **Value components** amounts well).

By doing this you don't delete and create markers all the time which means that the data leaks are stopped.

It is our way of doing things for now. If you have a better suggestion, I'd like to hear it.